# Search and replace depending on capitalization of letters

Tags: search, replace

I would like to replace `foo` with `bar` and `Foo` with `Bar`. I can do

```
:s/Foo/Bar/g
:s/foo/bar/g
```

Can I do this in one command?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but you can have a look at this plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish it achieve exactly that, and more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
:s/\cfoo/\=submatch(0)[0] ==# 'F' ? 'Bar' : 'bar'/g
```

The replacement part of the substitution command is an expression which tests whether the first character of the pattern is `F`.  If it is, the expression returns `Bar`, otherwise `bar`.